# How do I get access to another Model/Record for content in a prawn table cell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a PDF with a table (Prawn & Prawn-Table) where all educational objectives (EO) of a certain chapter are displayed with their use cases (UC). I get the EO straight but don't know exactly how to get the UC into the cell. 
Here is my code. Maybe someone has an idea or knows how to do it better than me.
Thanks in advance!

```
class UseCase < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :educational_objectives
end

class EducationalObjective < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :use_cases
end
```

app/pdfs/chapter_pdf.rb

```
require 'prawn'

class ChapterPdf < Prawn::Document
    def initialize(eo, chapter)
        @educational_objectives = eo
        @chapter = chapter
        @subject_id = @chapter.subject_id

        chapter_header
        chapter_text
        items
    end

    ...

    def items
        table_data = []

        @educational_objectives.map do |item|
            table_data << [item.position, item.educational_objective, use_cases(item.id)]
        end
        ...
    end

    def use_cases(id)
      ucs = @educational_objectives.joins(:use_cases).
                                where(educational_objectives: {id: id}).
                                select(:use_case)
      ucs.join do |uc|
        uc
      end
    end
end
```

When I look into the server log, I see this:

```
SELECT "use_case" FROM "educational_objectives" INNER JOIN "educational_objectives_use_cases" ON "educational_objectives_use_cases"."educational_objective_id" = "educational_objectives"."id" INNER JOIN "use_cases" ON "use_cases"."id" = "educational_objectives_use_cases"."use_case_id" WHERE "educational_objectives"."chapter_id" = ? AND "educational_objectives"."id" = ?  [["chapter_id", 9], ["id", 169]]

SELECT  1 AS one FROM "educational_objectives" INNER JOIN "educational_objectives_use_cases" ON "educational_objectives_use_cases"."educational_objective_id" = "educational_objectives"."id" INNER JOIN "use_cases" ON "use_cases"."id" = "educational_objectives_use_cases"."use_case_id" WHERE "educational_objectives"."chapter_id" = ? AND "educational_objectives"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["chapter_id", 9], ["id", 171], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And in my PDF I see in the cell

```
#<EducationalObjective:0x00007f8569997370>#<EducationalObjecti
ve:0x00007f85699971e0>#<EducationalObjective:0x00007f85699970
50>
```

Where is my mistake? And then I want to display it separated by comma...
Yes, I'm a newbie and very thankful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `has_and_belongs_to_many` association provides [a number of helper methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) - for your case, you'll be able to call `educational_objective.use_cases` to return a collection of the associated records.

This means you can remove your `use_cases` method and use something like the following:

```
  table_data = @educational_objectives.map do |item|
    [item.position, item.educational_objective, item.use_cases]
  end
```

As you're using `map`, there's no need to use an array defined outside of this.

This assumes `item` in the above example is an instance of `EducationalObjective`, although I'm slightly confused by that as you're also calling `item.educational_objective`.

Let me know if that clears anything up for you or if you've any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, SRack. I've tried it as you've described but get an error message (unrecognized table content when I use 'use_cases').

Comment: Maybe because I have sometimes many UCs for one EO? Therefore I thought I have to map them in order to get them as a string?!? [The confusion about item.educational_objective is understandable, but under this label I store the text of every EO.] I'll check the helper methods. Maybe I find something.

Comment: `use_cases` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` with the objects, whether one's present or many. I'm not sure what you're doing with `table_data`, but you're right - at some point you'll need to either select one or `map` them. I feel like this answers the question of how to access them - my advice would to be to persist a little with the `use_cases` mapping and pop in a fresh question when you hit another hurdle.

Comment: Thanks! If I use my method as in my question and do a ucs.size on it, I get the correct answer for every EO. But now, how can I get them out of the DB and into the cell? When I look into the server log I see a query for a non-existent 'use_case_text'...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help further without info on your schema, and I'm unsure what your new logs are referring to without seeing it.